# Get title,location, timezone, startdate and enddate values

Tags: ios7, nsmutablearray, ekevent, ekeventstore

How to access location value from events which is a NSMutableArray. When i try to use  NSLog(@"Event Title:%@", [[events objectAtIndex:i] location]);, compiler is throwing **Multiple methods named 'location' found with mismatched result, parameter type or attributes**. How to get location value from this events.

events (
    "EKEvent <0x94a9360>\n{\n\t EKEvent <0x94a9360>\n{\t title = \t\tSdsdfsd; \n\t **location** = \t(null); \n\t calendar = \tEKCalendar <0x9497b90> {title = Calendar; type = Local; allowsModify = YES; color = #1BADF8;}; \n\t alarms = \t\t(null); \n\t URL = \t\t\t(null); \n\t lastModified = 2014-07-31 13:35:52 +0000; \n\t timeZone = \tAsia/Kolkata (GMT+5:30) offset 19800 \n}; \n\t **location** = \t(null); \n\t startDate = \t2014-08-01 13:30:00 +0000; \n\t endDate = \t\t2014-08-01 14:30:00 +0000; \n\t allDay = \t\t0; \n\t floating = \t0; \n\t recurrence = \t(null); \n\t attendees = \t(null) \n};"
)

Answer (score 0):

If you have array of EKEvent object then you can loop through the array to get the required data as below

```
for (int i = 0; i < events.count; i++)
{
   EKEvent *event = [events objectAtIndex:i];
   NSLog(@"Title: %@\n",event.title);
   NSLog(@"Location: %@\n",event.location);
   NSLog(@"TimeZone: %@\n",event.timeZone);
   NSLog(@"StartDate: %@\n",event.startDate);
   NSLog(@"EndDate: %@\n",event.endDate);
}
```